# How can I see the fancy prompt in Byobu on Windows?

Tags: 14.04, windows, fonts, byobu, unicode

I installed a new Ubuntu server on 14.04 and need to access it using Windows. I am currently using PuTTYTray, and I installed the Ubuntu fonts and set Ubuntu Mono as my default font in order to get the Ubuntu logo in the corner to work in byobu.

However, the fancy prompt doesn't work. While I could edit the prompt or alt+f5 to switch to the non-UTF charmap, I'd rather see the prompt as I rather like it!

This is what it looks like on my computer:

[image: Using the Ubuntu Monospace font on Windows]

This is what it looks like in gnome-terminal with the fancy prompt (example not mine):

[image: An example image pulled from a blog post where the fancy prompt works]

Is there a way to get this to work on Windows as well?

If it's relevant, I am running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Anna.

I have no exact solution to your issue (looks like bug with some unicode symbols support in PuTTY/KiTTY), but you can change this symbol to any you like. For example this: ».

See the file /usr/share/byobu/profiles/bashrc. There are the next strings:

```
# MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+27EB, Pe): ⟫
printf "%s" "⟫"
```

Change the symbol and restart you terminal session.